# Accessing XML documentation using Type class

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way I can access Xml documentation from the type class, eg:

```
/// <summary>
/// Blah blah blah
/// </summary>
public class Foo{}
```

`Debug.Print(typeOf(Foo).XmlSummary);`

Would result in `Blah blah blah`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, xml comments are parsed by VS and other tools to generate documentation, but, like regular comments, are not included in the generated assembly, so the type's metadata does not know about them.

If you need to do this for your classes, you could use a custom attribute:

```
using System;

class SummaryAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Value {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public SummaryAttribute(string value) {
        Value = value;    
    }
}

[Summary("Blah")]
class Foo { 
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var summaryAttributes = typeof(Foo).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SummaryAttribute), false);
        if (summaryAttributes.Length != 0) {
            SummaryAttribute summary = (SummaryAttribute)summaryAttributes[0];
            Console.WriteLine(summary.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. Should have recognized they are treated like normal comments. Thanks!!